# Implementing an inner anonymous action listener

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, inner-classes, anonymous-class

I've been trying to implement this action listener as stated above but keep receiving two errors:

```
-Cannot instantiate the type ActionListener
-void is an invalid type for the variable incrementAction
```

I've been looking up similar examples but they all seem to point to the same method of implementing it.
This is where I've got to.

```
        increment.addActionListener(new ActionListener());{
        public void incrementAction(ActionEvent e){
            this.incrementCount();
            this.setTextField();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you have a `;` there? Where do you think the anonymous class definition starts?

Comment: Oh, sorry that wasn't supposed to be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature of the `ActionListener` method is:

`public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)`

```
JButton increment  = new JButton();
increment.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("ActionEvent received! ");
    }
});
```

Comment: Cheers for that, the final problem I've got is that I can't seem to make use of my two methods, .incrementCount and .setTextField which I created within the same class.