# New a Frame instance instead of creating a class instance has caused problem

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, awt, actionlistener

I'm new to Java AWT programing. And here is a simple code which my professor taught us.
The functionality is when clicking the button, the console will print "click".

```
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;

 public class myApp  extends Frame implements ActionListener{
    //static Frame frm = new Frame("Using Frame frm = new Frame()");
    static myApp frm = new myApp();
    static Button btn = new Button("click");
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        frm.setVisible(true);
        frm.setSize(400,400);
        frm.add(btn);
        btn.addActionListener(frm);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        Button clicked =(Button)e.getSource();
        System.out.println("click!");
    }
 }
```

I tried to modify the

`static myApp frm = new myApp();`

into
`static Frame frm = new Frame("Using Frame frm = new Frame()");`

Then I got an error which says

> myApp.java:13: error: incompatible types: Frame cannot be converted to ActionListener
> btn.addActionListener(frm);
> ^
> Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
> 1 error

What I want to asked is
(1) What is this error and how to fix it?
(2) if myApp has extended Frame, is easily to know that we can create a instance based on  myApp class,which is a  `java.awt.frame` and has all of the fields and functions of `java.awt.frame`, but what is the benefit of it? Why not just use `Frame frm = new Frame()` instead?

Tks. for helping, and may all you are safe during the epidemic.

Comment: The message states the problem precisely, `Frame` doesn't implement `ActionListener`. But `MyApp` does, and that's why it works.

Comment: 1) The error occurs because if you make `frm` into a `Frame` instead of `myApp` object, `frm` does no longer implement `ActionListener`, and therefore the `btn.addActionListener(frm)` will tell you that `frm` is not an instance of `ActionListener` to be added here. --- To fix it, you could simply create a different implementation of `ActionListener` which you then add to the `btn`. 2) There is only a benefit if you actually want to change the behavior / functionality of the default `Frame`. If you don't do that (like in your example) there is no real benefit.

Comment: @maloomeister The benefit is seen right here in the question. You can add `implements ActionListener`. For example.

Comment: @user207421 but is that an actual benefit in this example? You could still do that if `MyApp` didn't `extends Frame` but still `implements ActionListener`. So that does not actually justify the `extends Frame` or does it?

Comment: @maloomeister He is asking about the benefit of extending `Frame` *versus* using it directly.

Comment: Thanks you guys for explanation, now I got it that Frame does not implement `ActionListener`. BTW, @maloomeister what do you mean to implementation ActionListener, you mean create a new class and override the `addActionListerer `function?

Comment: @yu-hsuanHo Yes that is one way. Another approach you could take is to write an anonymous implementation of your `ActionListener`, ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22129861/11441011)). This way you don't have to implement actionlistener. Use this approach if this `ActionListener` will never be reused.

Comment: You should be using Swing instead of AWT. Swing components start with "J", JFrame, JButton. Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Make Frame](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) for a basic example.